# Laravel Factory incorrect datetime value

Tags: laravel

In a Laravel Factory I have:

```
'created_at' => now()->subDays(mt_rand(1,90))->subHours(mt_rand(1,23))->toDateTimeString()
```

This previously worked fine, I think it was on Laravel 7.2. By 'worked fine' I mean I ran this to insert 10.000s or more rows and it never failed. After updating to 7.10.3 I now get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2020-03-29 02:10:11' for column 'created_at'
```

It does actually insert a few hundred rows before failing, so it seems to be a specific date or time that fails. Of the rows that are actually inserted some also have 2020-03-29 as the date and some have 02:10:11 as the time so I don't know why this is an 'invalid format'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

March 29, 2020 was when daylight savings time (DST) started in Europe. I'm assuming you are in the Central European Time (CET) timezone, where time moves forward 1 hour from 2AM to 3AM, so there was no 2:10 AM, making your datetime invalid.

You have a couple options:

1. You can update your database/database server to use UTC.
2. You can update your Laravel application timezone to match your database server timezone (`app.timezone` config key).
3. You can update your factory to call `setTimezone(/* db timezone */)` on your Carbon instance before converting it to a string (this will ensure Carbon does not create an invalid datetime for the database timezone).